# Kendo Dialog + Grid, how to pass grid name to functions on a page with many grids

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have many kendo grids on one page with custom kendo dialog delete function, and I'd like to get the exact grid name of the delete custom function:

```
.Name("RevenueGrid1")
                      .Columns(columns =>
                      {
                          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.FundAgencyId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.FundAgencyList, "Id", "FundAgencyDisplayText").Title("Fund/BC").Width(300).Filterable(ft => ft.Cell(c => { c.Operator("startswith"); c.InputWidth(300); c.ShowOperators(false); }));
                          columns.Bound(p => p.FundSource).Title("Source/Desc").Width(300).HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#= FundSource #" });
                          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.RevenueObject, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.BudgetObjectList, "Id", "BudgetObjectDisplayText").EditorTemplateName("GridRevenueObject").Width(300).Title("Revenue Source").Filterable(ft => ft.Cell(c => { c.Operator("startswith"); c.InputWidth(300); c.ShowOperators(false); }));
                          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.RevenueSubObject, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.SubObjectList, "Id", "SubObjectDisplayText").Width(300).Title("Dept. Rev Source").Filterable(ft => ft.Cell(c => { c.Operator("startswith"); c.InputWidth(300); c.ShowOperators(false); }));
                          columns.Bound(p => p.RevenueAmount).Title("Amount")
                                      .Width(150).ClientTemplate("#if(RevenueAmount != null){##= kendo.format('{0:N0}', (RevenueAmount)) ##} else { } #").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" }).ClientFooterTemplate("Total: <span class='customFooterTotal'>#=kendo.toString((sum == null) ? 0 : sum, 'n0') #</span>").FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" });
                          columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Delete").Click("showDeleteConfirmation").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:95%" })).Width(87).Visible(Model.CanEditForm);
                      })
```

The dialog:

```
<div id="dialog">
@(Html.Kendo()
        .Dialog()
        .Width(200)
        .Name("DeleteConfirmation")
        .Modal(true)
        .Title("Confirm Delete")
        .Content("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
        .Visible(false)
        .Actions(a =>
        {
            a.Add().Text("Yes").Action("confirmDelete").Primary(true);
            a.Add().Text("No").Action("cancelDelete");
        })
)
</div>
```

In this function, how do I grab the grid name:

```
 function showDeleteConfirmation(e) {
//how to get grid name?
}
```

and pass it to the delete function:

```
 function confirmDelete(e) {
 //how to get grid name?
}
```

Comment: Pass a parameter. Click("showDeleteConfirmation('RevenueGrid1')")

Comment: @SteveGreene Works! Thank you!